# Azure Functions model binding

Tags: c#, azure, postman, azure-functions

I've created an Azure Function and I'm running it locally:

```
[FunctionName("HttpTriggerCSharpSet")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Set([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] MyDocument req, TraceWriter log)
{
   // ...
}
```

Notice that `MyDocument` is the first parameter instead of `HttpRequestMessage`. I've read in the documentation that this approach should work, and it seems very similar to ASP.NET model binding (in my mind, anyway). `MyDocument` is a POCO with just 3 properties.

```
public class MyDocument
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ShoeSize { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
}
```

When I POST to the function like so (I'm using Postman):

[image: POST with Postman to Azure Function]

I get an error message: `[8/8/2017 2:21:07 PM] Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerCSharpSet. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'req'. System.Net.Http.Formatting: No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'MyDocument' from content` (which you can also see in the screenshot of Postman above)

I've tried form-data and x-www-form-urlencoded and even raw from Postman, same error every time. I've also tried switching back to `HttpRequestMessage` and using `req.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyDocument>`, and I get a similar error. Am I constructing my POST incorrectly, or am I writing my Azure Function incorrectly. In either case, what's the correct way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to specify the header:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

then the following body should work for your code:

```
{
    "Name": "myUserName",
    "Balance": 123.0,
    "ShoeSize": 30
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be JSON that's submitted to an Azure Function? Form encoded doesn't work? Is that documented someplace I didn't notice?