# How can I bind a collection of models in a HTTP triggered Azure Function?

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function v2. The function is triggered by a POST HTTP request and is being given a list of account.

Here is the Azure Function:

```
public sealed class AccountFunction
{
    private readonly ILogger m_logger;

    public AccountFunction(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        m_logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AccountFunction>();
    }

    [FunctionName("AccountFunction")]
    public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "v1/accounts")] List<Account> accounts)
    {
        m_logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        return new OkObjectResult(accounts);
    }
}
```

The Account class is a simple POCO:

```
public class Account
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I start the function and then I send the following POST request:

```
http://localhost:7071/api/v1/accounts
```

I set the JSON collection in the body of the request:

```
[{ 
    "name":"A",
    "description":"covfefe"
},
 { 
    "name":"B",
    "description":"huuuggge"
}]
```

The Azure Function returns an empty collection and the traces did not show any errors:

```
[2019-03-13 1:34:13 PM] Executing HTTP request: { 
[2019-03-13 1:34:13 PM]   "requestId": "3ee0483f-7e26-4bbf-a4ea-550dbbd86563", [2019-03-13 1:34:13 PM]   "method": "POST", 
[2019-03-13 1:34:13 PM]   "uri": "/api/v1/accounts" 
[2019-03-13 1:34:13 PM] } 
[2019-03-13 1:34:13 PM] Request successfully matched the route with name 'AccountFunction' and template 'api/v1/accounts' 
[2019-03-13 1:34:14 PM] Executing 'AccountFunction' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=92b40b1a-8bb1-4699-a590-d057c5eb7353) 
[2019-03-13 1:34:14 PM] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request. 
[2019-03-13 1:34:14 PM] Executed 'AccountFunction' (Succeeded, Id=92b40b1a-8bb1-4699-a590-d057c5eb7353) [2019-03-13 1:34:14 PM] Executed HTTP request: { 
[2019-03-13 1:34:14 PM]   "requestId": "3ee0483f-7e26-4bbf-a4ea-550dbbd86563",
[2019-03-13 1:34:14 PM]   "method": "POST", [2019-03-13 1:34:14 PM]   "uri": "/api/v1/accounts", 
[2019-03-13 1:34:14 PM]   "identities": [ [2019-03-13 1:34:14 PM]     { 
[2019-03-13 1:34:14 PM]       "type": "WebJobsAuthLevel", 
[2019-03-13 1:34:14 PM]       "level": "Admin" 
[2019-03-13 1:34:14 PM] } 
[2019-03-13 1:34:14 PM]   ], 
[2019-03-13 1:34:14 PM]   "status": 200, 
[2019-03-13 1:34:14 PM]   "duration": 517 
[2019-03-13 1:34:14 PM] }
```

While debugging the function, I found out that the accounts parameter was not properly filled in:

[image: Accounts is empty]

**Question**

How can I bind a collection of models in an Azure Function?

I am running the latest Azure Function Core tools 2.4.419 and the Azure Function runtime 2.0.12332.0.

The Function App is targeting .NET Core 2.1.

**Update**

I have tried several other options.

The first one is to have a new `Accounts` class that derives from a `List<Account>` but the result is the same.

```
public class Accounts : List<Account>
{        
}
```

The second test is to have the Accounts containing a List of account as a property:

```
public class Accounts
{        
    public List<Account> Items {get;set;}
}
```

Then again same result except that the returned object is now:

```
{
    "items": null
}
```

Comment: I believe model binding is case sensitive. Try changing your json request to match your POCO names (including the capitalization)

Comment: @Daniel It is not :) I changed it though -just to be sure- but it does not change anything. If I changed the function's parameter to Account (instead of a collection), it does work, whether the json properties are pascal case or camel case.

Comment: Call me out if I'm talking nonsense as I don't know Azure Functions all that well, but do they support model binding? I know MVC goes through its process of model binding to your parameters type members, but every example I've seen for Azure Functions make use of the `HttpRequestMessage` `.Content` member. Your method signature should be `public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "v1/accounts")] HttpRequestMessage req)`

Comment: @ColinM Azure Function does support model binding (as can be seen in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571138/azure-functions-model-binding)). If I change the parameter to specify a Account type (and change the HTTP request to add an account in the Body), the binding does work.

Comment: On second glance, I'll call myself out - I'm talking nonsense. Binding is supported https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#httptriggerusage

Comment: Have you tried the following request? `{"accounts": [{"name": "A"}]}` Your current request doesn't specify what your `accounts` variable is, and you haven't used `FromBodyAttribute`

Comment: @ColinM Yes. No success either...

Comment: Here's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3370) which describes the problem, and the particular [line of code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/cdeb65faacf04c53845fb76c4b513c9998fc97de/src/WebJobs.Extensions.Http/Utility.cs#L29) causing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have attempted, and reproduced this issue locally also. First I tried with a single `Account` object, and then updated the method signature to accept `List<Account>`. On a quick inspection, I found the following [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3370) describing this behavior.

There's a [comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3370#issuecomment-436115844) on that issue which refers to the following [source file line](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/cdeb65faacf04c53845fb76c4b513c9998fc97de/src/WebJobs.Extensions.Http/Utility.cs#L29) where the code explicitly excludes arrays

```
var additionalBindingData = parsed.Children<JProperty>()
    .Where(p => p.Value != null && (p.Value.Type != JTokenType.Array))
```

It seems like the only way to achieve this is with a [workaround](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3370#issuecomment-424779907).

Another approach would be to use the `ReadAsAsync<T>` extension method.

```
namespace StackOverflow.AccountsQuestion
{
    public sealed class AccountFunction
    {
        private readonly ILogger m_logger;

        public AccountFunction(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            m_logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AccountFunction>();
        }

        [FunctionName("AccountFunction")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "v1/accounts")] HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            m_logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            var accounts = await request.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Account>>();
            return new OkObjectResult(accounts);
        }
    }

    public class Account
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kzrystof I've added a tested code snippet for a shorter workaround.