# Azure Function with HTTP trigger fails to bind model from JSON payload (.NET 5 out-of-proc )

Tags: c#, json, azure-functions, .net-5

I am running an isolated process function that is failing to bind the input model from the JSON payload.

This is my function:

```csharp
[Function("AddChip")]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> AddChip([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous,
 "post", Route = "chip")] Chip chip, HttpRequestData req, FunctionContext executionContext)
{
            
    var logger = executionContext.GetLogger("Function1");
    logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    var result = await _chipService.UpsertChipAsync(chip);

    var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(result);
    return response;
}
```

And this is my `Chip` class:

```csharp
public class Chip
{
    public string Id {  get; set; }
    public double Balance { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
}
```

But when I call it from Insomnia making sure the `Content-Type application/json` header is set with this body:

```json
{
    "Id": "1",
    "Balance": 0,
    "Created": "2001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Updated": "2001-01-01T00:00:00"
}
```

I get an error message saying that the `chip` parameter could not be converted:

`Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Diagnostics.Exceptions.FunctionInputConverterException: Error converting 1 input parameters for Function 'AddChip': Cannot convert input parameter 'chip' to type 'Models.Chip' from type 'Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.GrpcHttpRequestData'.`

I have tried unsuccessfully:

- Removing the `HttpRequestData` parameter,
- Different classes and payloads,
- Different `AuthorizationLevel`

It seems related to gRPC somehow as the error references `GrpcHttpRequestData`.

Different sources like [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#payload) or [this Rick van den Bosch post](https://www.rickvandenbosch.net/blog/azure-functions-binding-to-a-property/) or even other Stack Overflow answers like [Azure Functions model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571138/azure-functions-model-binding) imply this should work, but it does not.

Comment: This seems annoying ++, what happens if you remove `Chip chip,` altogether, i am just curious ?

Comment: I assume this is Azure Functions on .NET 5?

Comment: @TheGeneral It works without `Chip chip`. The `RequestData` comes through and `req.Body` contains the JSON which can be deserialized correctly.

Comment: @IanKemp, Correct .NET 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stephen mentioned in the other answer, there is no fully fledged model binding capability today in the .net 5 azure function(out of process model). Your request payload is available in the `Body` property of the `HttpRequestData` instance and you may de-serialize it inside your function.

The below example uses JsonSerializer from `System.Text.Json` namespace.

```
static JsonSerializerOptions SerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
};

[Function("AddChip")]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> AddChip(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "chip")] HttpRequestData req,
    FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    Chip chip = null;

    if (req.Body is not null)
    {
        chip = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Chip>(req.Body, SerializerOptions);
    }

    var logger = executionContext.GetLogger("Function1");
    logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request for." + chip?.Id);

    var result = await _chipService.UpsertChipAsync(chip);

    var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(result);
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Azure Functions .NET 5 uses the new out-of-proc model, which is currently very limited in terms of model binding.

In the case of HTTP requests, your method gets a `HttpRequestData`. Any mapping of request body or URI parameters must be done by your code.

Comment: The documentation of out-of-proc definitely suggests bindings should work https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#bindings Am I missing something or do you have any links supporting the contrary?

Comment: @AntonioDlp: That section says "For HTTP triggers, you must use HttpRequestData and HttpResponseData to access the request and response data." I expect they're *planning* to add support for it, but I believe it is not there yet.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I was reading it incorrectly. It's not very clear as the previous paragraph references POCOs.